# Javascript twos complement

Tags: javascript, python, math, binary

The following python code seems to work very well to het the twos complement of a number:

```
def twos_comp(self, val, bits):
    if (val & (1 << (bits - 1))) != 0:
        val -= 1 << bits
    return val
```

It is used as `num = self.twos_comp(int(binStr, 2), len(binStr))`
where binStr is a string that contains an arbitrary length binary number.

I need to do the exact same thing in javascript (for node.js).  I've been fighting it all day and am about to resign from the human race.  Clearly binary / bitwise math is not my strong suit.

Could someone please assist so I can go on to more productive time wasting :-)

Comment: what code got you closest to the solution, and can you include it here (so we don't have to write it from scratch) ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function toTwosComplement(integer, numberBytes, dontCheckRange) {   
    // @integer - > the integer to convert
    // @numberBytes -> the number of bytes representing the number (defaults to 1 if not specified)

    var numberBits = (numberBytes || 1) * 8;

    // make sure its in range given the number of bits
    if (!dontCheckRange && (integer < (-(1 << (numberBits - 1))) || integer > ((1 << (numberBits - 1)) - 1))) 
        throw "Integer out of range given " + numberBytes + " byte(s) to represent.";

    // if positive, return the positive value
    if (integer >= 0)
        return integer;

    // if negative, convert to twos complement representation
    return ~(((-integer) - 1) | ~((1 << numberBits) - 1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks George, I'll give it a try and report back

Comment: George - is the purpose of numberBytes to set the number of digits possible for the maximum expected value?

Comment: By specifying numberBytes you can represent number in how many bytes you want. e.g. if you pass 4, your number will be represented in 32 bits.